# Separating two URLs which float right

Tags: html, css

First of all, I am not an `HTML` expert at all. This question might be too simple for you.

I have two URLs that I keep at right of the page. I want to separate these to URLs into separate lines. I know by adding a `<br>` or even adding a single character in between of them, they become separate. But what is the proper `CSS` way to fix this?

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <a style="float: right;" href="/edit/1">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a style="float: right;" href="/delete/1">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options...

- As you mentioned you can use `br` which will insert a line-break
- You can also use `width: 100%;` which will make each element the full width of it's parent, putting both links on seperte lines. Using this method you'd probably want to push the parent container to float right OR you can just use `text-align: right;` instead of `float`
- `clear: both;` would also do the job by stopping elements from floating next to it.

Either way, the result is the same!

On a sidenote, the divs aren't necessary for your example (unless you have some css applied to them that you haven't shared) so I'd remove those if you're not using them for anything.

```css
a {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <a style="float: right;" href="/edit/1">Edit</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a style="float: right;" href="/delete/1">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these properties to the container of `a` elements:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Another variant is to set `display: block` to the `a` elements.

Comment: I tried `display: block` which did not make an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Style the anchor's parent element to place them where you want them, and give each anchor tag a `display: block`:

```css
.menu {
  text-align: right
}

.menu__anchor {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a class="menu__anchor" href="/edit/1">Edit</a>
  <a class="menu__anchor" href="/delete/1">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <div><a href="/edit/1">Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href="/delete/1">Delete</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `display:flex` like this:

```css
    .flexbox {
     display:flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="flexbox">
        <div>
            <a href="/edit/1">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="/delete/1">Delete</a>
        </div>
   </div>
```